# Limit existence

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disprove that for a fixed positive real $x$, the existence of $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\left(e^x\right)^{^{m}}}{\left(e^y\right)^{^{(2 \sqrt{2})^{^{s}}}}}$$
such that $y<x$, and $s$ is defined to be $\frac{m}{2}$ when $m$ is even, and when $m$ is even $s=\frac{m+1}{2}$ 
$\underline{Solution}$:

As I see the limit exists and equals to zero becuase for any large $x$ and very very small $y$, we can find such an $m$ such that $xm< y(2\sqrt2)^s.$ But I am struggling with proving that by choosing such an $N$ for any given $\epsilon>0$. I would appreciate it any help or hint about that.

Thank you.

Comment: Question garbled. Not clear what's supposed to be proved about that limit. Also, not clear what is to be defined as $2\sqrt2$. Please edit for clarity.

Comment: Just ignore $\rho$ and consider $2 \sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Is not more clear now?

Comment: Limit...as $m$ goes to infinity? as $y$ goes to zero? as $my$ goes to $\pi$? Still not clear.

Comment: as $m \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: "$s$ is defined to be $\frac{m}{2}$ when $m$ is even, and when $m$ is even $s=\frac{m+1}{2}$" is worse than unclear, it's self-contradictory.

Comment: OK, Ahmed, I edited for you. But please attend to the comment by @David.

Comment: PLEASE, Ahmed, attend to the comment by @David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(e^x\right)^{^{m}}}{\left(e^y\right)^{^{(2 \sqrt{2})^{^{s_m}}}}}
&=e^{xm-y\varrho^{s_m}}
\end{align}
where $\varrho=2\sqrt 2$ and $s_m=\frac{2m+1-(-1)^m}4$.
Consequently, $s\sim\frac m2\to+\infty$ as $m\to+\infty$, hence
$$y\varrho^{s_m}\xrightarrow{m\to+\infty}
\begin{cases}
+\infty&y>0\\
-\infty&y<0
\end{cases}$$
Since $xm=o(y\varrho^{s_m})$ as $m\to+\infty$ we have
$$xm-y\varrho^{s_m}\xrightarrow{m\to+\infty}
\begin{cases}
-\infty&y>0\\
+\infty&y\leq 0
\end{cases}$$
hence
$$\frac{\left(e^x\right)^{^{m}}}{\left(e^y\right)^{^{(2 \sqrt{2})^{^{s_m}}}}}\xrightarrow{m\to+\infty}
\begin{cases}
0^+&y>0\\
+\infty&y\leq 0
\end{cases}$$